# Android. Как получить json из страницы?

Tags: java, android

Код

```
public class getjson {

String Query;
JSONObject jo = null;

public getjson(String url){
    Query = url;
    getJson();
}
private void getJson() {
    try {
        // Create a new HTTP Client
        DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Setup the get request
        HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(Query);

        // Execute the request in the client
        HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
        // Grab the response
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();

        // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
        jo = new JSONObject(json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getJo(){
    return jo.toString();
}
```

}

Приложение вылетает при исполнении кода.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - тогда вам надо запускать запрос в сеть не в основном потоке

Comment: `Apache HttpClient` уже давно deprecated, не стоит на нем новый код писать.